# How to dynamically populate email variable in tracking-script for Contactform7 submit

Tags: wordpress, email, tracking, contact-form-7

On my site we are using ActiveCampaign site tracking.We are using below script in our site for tracking.I want to get the email of the customers who submitted the contact form 7. How i dynamically populate email variable from contactform7.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var trackcmp_email = '';
    var trackcmp = document.createElement("script");
    trackcmp.async = true;
    trackcmp.type = 'text/javascript';
    trackcmp.src = '//trackcmp.net/visit?actid=609779006&e='+encodeURIComponent(trackcmp_email)+'&r='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    var trackcmp_s = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    if (trackcmp_s.length) {
        trackcmp_s[0].parentNode.appendChild(trackcmp);
    } else {
        var trackcmp_h = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
        trackcmp_h.length && trackcmp_h[0].appendChild(trackcmp);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want email address when successfully submitted the form or just click on submit button and change dynamic email address ?

Comment: I want email address when successfully submitted the form

Comment: Both will get then i will more happy @dipmala

Comment: But question is that this script work when page is load if you change it dynamically then we can change the variable dynamically but it won't work without page refresh, ultimately tracking won;t work as per your desire.

Comment: I think it work